# Prove that if $T: F^n → F^m$ is linear, then there exists a unique $m×n$ matrix $C$ such that $T = L_C.$ In fact, $C = [T]^γ_β.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix with entries from $F.$ Then the left-multiplication transformation $L_A : F^n → F^m$ is linear. Furthermore, we assume $B$ is any other $m × n$ matrix (with entries from $F$) and $β$ and $γ$ are the standard ordered bases for $F^n$ and $F^m,$ respectively.

Prove that  if $T: F^n → F^m$ is linear, then there exists a unique $m×n$ matrix $C$ such that $T = L_C.$ In fact, $C = [T]^γ_β.$

The solution given is as follows:

> Let $C = [T]^γ_β.$
>
> We know that,
>
> If $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces having ordered bases $β$ and $γ,$ respectively, and  $T: V → W$ be linear. Then, for each $u ∈ V,$ we have $[T(u)]_γ = [T]_γ^β[u]_β.$
>
> We have $[T(x)]_γ = [T]_γ^β[x]_β,$ or $T(x) = Cx = L_C (x)$ for all $x ∈ F_n.$ So $T = L_C .$ The uniqueness of $C$ follows from the fact that, "$L_A = L_B$ if and only if $A = B.$"

---

However, I don't understand how did they write, "...or $T(x) = Cx = L_C (x)$ for all $x ∈ F_n$" from $[T(x)]_γ = [T]_γ^β[x]_β.$ It seems that $[T(x)]_γ = [T]_γ^
β[x]_β=C[x]_{\beta},$ but I don't get how did it imply $ T(x) = Cx = L_C (x)$ ?

I don't get  why can we  replace $[T(x)]_γ$ in  $[T(x)]_γ = [T]_γ^β[x]_β$ by $T(x)$ and $[x]_{\beta}$ by $x$ *just like that*?

Answer (score 0):

$\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the standard bases for $F^n$ and $F^m$, so $[T(x)]_{\gamma}$ is just $T(x)$ written in terms of the way we *usually* write $T(x)$. Similarly, $[x]_{\beta} = x$.

Comment: But I don't get  why can we  replace $[T(x)]_γ$ in  $[T(x)]_γ = [T]_γ^β[x]_β$ by $T(x)$ and $[x]_{\beta}$ by $x$ *just like that*?

Comment: Suppose I said that $\gamma = ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix})$. What is $\left[ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\right]_{\gamma}$?

Comment: Thanks a ton! I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same doubt at the exact spot some time ago. If it helps here is how I understand it:

Since $\beta=\{e_{1}, \ldots, e_{n}\}$ and $\gamma= \{e_{1}, \ldots, e_{m}\}$ are the standard ordered basis from $\mathbb{F}^{n}$, $\mathbb{F}^{m}$ respectively, then by Theorem 1.8 [Linear Algebra 4thEd, Insel&Friedberg], every vector $ v\in V$ and $w\in W$ can be **uniquely expressed** in the form:

$$ v= a_{1}e_{1} + \ldots + a_{n}e_{n}$$
$$ w= b_{1}e_{1} + \ldots + b_{m}e_{m}$$

And we have $x \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$ and $T(x)\in \mathbb{F}^{m}$, then

$$x =       
\begin{pmatrix}
        a_{1}' \\
        \vdots \\
        a_{n}' \\
\end{pmatrix}
=  a_{1}'e_{1} + \ldots + a_{n}'e_{n}
$$
$$T(x) =       
\begin{pmatrix}
        b_{1}' \\
        \vdots \\
        b_{n}' \\
      \end{pmatrix}
=  b_{1}'e_{1} + \ldots + b_{m}'e_{m}
$$
Now by **the definition of the coordinate vector with respect to a basis** (Pg.80) [Linear Algebra 4thEd, Insel&Friedberg] we have that for all $x\in \mathbb{F}^{n}$:
$$[x]_{\beta}= [a_{1}'e_{1}+ \cdots + a_{n}'e_{n}]_{\beta} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        a_{1}' \\
        \vdots \\
        a_{n}' \\
\end{pmatrix}
= x
$$
$$[T(x)]_{\gamma}= [b_{1}'e_{1}+ \cdots + b_{m}'e_{m}]_{\gamma} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
        b_{1}' \\
        \vdots \\
        b_{m}' \\
\end{pmatrix}
= T(x)
$$

By the last results $[T(x)]_{\gamma} = [T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} \cdot [x]_{\beta}$ becomes:
$$T(x) = [T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} 
\cdot x \quad \text{   for all } 
x \in \mathbb{F}^{n} \quad (Eq.1)$$
And by the definition of **left-multiplication transformation** (Pg.92) [Linear Algebra 4thEd, Insel&Friedberg] we have:

$$
[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma} \cdot x = L_{[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}}(x) \quad \text{  for all } x \in \mathbb{F}^{n} \quad (Eq.2)
$$

$Eq.(1)$ and $Eq.(2)$ implies $T(x) = L_{[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}}(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{F}^{n}$. Therefore $T = L_{[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}}$

Define $C:=[T]_{\beta}^{\gamma}$ and its done, $T=L_{C}$

Sorry if I went on too long, I did it for clarity, I hope it helps.